# How to apply background-color to the whole area of class

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to change a background color in a whole class area (class="test_detail"), but only the color behind the text changed.

I use Rails 4.

index.html.erb

```
.
.
.
<% @calendar.each do |c| %>
.
.
.
<aside class="span7">
    <span class="test_detail">
      <% if c.day? %>
        <%= c.day %>
      <% else %>
        xxx
      <% end %>
      <br>
       xxx <%= link_to "xxx", 'http://xxx' %>
    </span>
</aside>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

custom.css.scss

```
.test_detail {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

`font-size` and `color` work, but `background-color` seems not to work.

Comment: yes as background color will only change the background not the text color for that you already used color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using a `span` and not a `div` - it is by default inline, so in this case you will only see the background color change directly behind the text.

http://www.cssreset.com/understanding-the-difference-between-div-and-span/

Comment: Thank you for your comment, invalidfunction. It works with `div` instead of `span`.